# Separate text into 2 part based on the end of text

Tags: regex

I have a text  :

```
365 days (1)
```

And want to using regex to separate them as different part with the end of the text always a pair of parenthesis and number inside, so the different part after separated should be : '365 days' and '(1)' .

I using this Regex and it work :

```
^([^(]+)[(]([0-9]+)[)]$
```

However, if my first part contain a parenthesis on it so it not work :

```
36(5) days (1)
```

I want it still separated to '36(5) days' and '(1)'

Please help me to fix this regex.

Note : I'm using ASP/VBScript/VB6 or C#/VB.NET .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the `(\d)` will be at the very last of the string, using `.*` in first group will do it for you.

```
^(.*)[(]([0-9]+)[)]$
```

You can use `\s+` in between the two groups to avoid picking trailing spaces at the first group as well.